# filtering column with combobox in angular ngtable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to implement 'custom filtering' in angularjs table using ngtable similar to [this example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/11), but in my case the 'data' are being fetched asynchronously and it takes some time. The problem I'm facing is that when accessing page, this function in controller (while other functions work fine) never runs, when debugging it just steps over it.

```
$scope.docNames = function(column) {
    var def = $q.defer(),
        arr = [],
        names = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(item){
        if (inArray(item.name, arr) === -1) {
            arr.push(item.name);
            docNames.push({
                'id': item.Name,
                'title': item.Name
            });
        }
    });
    def.resolve(docNames);
    return def;
};
```

My ngTable object:

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
    {
        page: 1,
        count: 10,
        sorting: {
            Date: 'desc'
        }
     },
     {
         total: 0,
         getData: function ($defer, params) {

             factory.getData().then(function (result) {
                 documents = result.data;

                 //filtering
                 var orderedData = params.filter() ?
                     $filter('filter')(documents, params.filter()) :
                     documents;

                 //sorting
                 orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                     $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) :
                     orderedData;

                 //pagination
                 $scope.documents = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                 params.total(orderedData.length);
                 $defer.resolve($scope.documents);
            });
       }
  });
```

My html:

```
<table data-ng-table="tableParams" data-show-filter="true" class="table table-striped">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="document in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ 'Name': 'select' }" filter-data="docNames($column)" data-sortable="'Name'">{{ document.Name }} </td>
        <td data-title="'Size'" filter="{ 'Size': 'text' }" data-sortable="'Size'">{{ document.Size }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Date'" data-sortable="'Date'">{{ document.Date }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As predicted, the 'documents' were not yet loaded when the 'docNames' list being evaluated. We resolved this by resolving defer before the first use of it:

```
var qDocse = $q.defer();
qDocs.resolve(factory.getData());
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
    {
        page: 1,
        count: 10,
        sorting: {
             Date: 'desc'
        }
    },
    {
        total: 0,
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            qDocs.promise.then(function (result) {
                documents = result.data;

                //filtering
                var orderedData = params.filter() ?
                    $filter('filter')(documents, params.filter()) :
                    documents;

                //sorting
                orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) :
                    orderedData;

                //pagination
                $scope.documents = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                params.total(orderedData.length);
                $defer.resolve($scope.documents);
            });
       }
  });
```

and

```
$scope.docNames = function (column) {
    var def = $q.defer(),
        arr = [],
        docNames = [];
    qDocs.promise.then(function (result) {
        angular.forEach(result.data, function (item) {
            if (inArray(item.Name, arr) === -1) {
                arr.push(item.Name);
                docNames.push({
                    'id': item.Name,
                    'title': item.Name
                    });
                }
            });
        });
     def.resolve(docNames);
     return def;
};
```